# Simple persistent queue software usable with python

Tags: linux, python, message-broker

I am in process of trying to select a [message queue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Message_queue) implementation for Linux that would support:

1. persistence, preferably using Sqlite3, but could be another backend
   or filesystem;
2. thread-safety;
3. recoverability: items can be read after process restart.
4. Python bindings for at least Python 2.7;
5. being as simple to use as possible (explained below);
6. would be reasonably good long-term choice in the sense that it (1) has an
   active community and (2) has ongoing development/support;
7. preferably have a version included in any recent Ubuntu LTS (eg.
   Ubuntu Xenial)
8. preferably queues are also accessible via network.

At the moment I have looked at [RabbitMQ with pika](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html) for python bindings and 
[persist-queue](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/persist-queue/0.3.4).

I like persist-queue, as it supports requirement 1-5; it is extremely simple -- it needs no broker, no specific setup etc. I am, however, totally unsure how reliable and how good a long-term choice it could be, as I see there is only a single developer and there is no usage info.

RabbitMQ looks like a mature product, which supports the requirements 1,4,6,7,8, but the concepts of channels, routing keys and exchanges are sort of surplus to my requirements. I do not know if it supports 2 and 3, but I assume it does.

I have found several older questions dealing with message queue software, but I wonder if by now there is anything new I should have a look at, which would meet my requirements.